# Modifying PoA Geth Ethereum blockchain: Creating a function to send messages to the signer node/address from any node

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, go-ethereum

Familiar with the codebase and the sections pertaining to node communication.
Requested Assistance: Guidance on the necessary steps and considerations to successfully achieve the desired functionality.
Any relevant resources or references that could aid in understanding and implementing the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your valuable assistance and expertise!

My objective is to create a new function within the PoA Geth Ethereum blockchain that allows sending messages exclusively to the signer node/address from any node in the network. By accomplishing this, I aim to gain a deeper understanding of the underlying mechanisms of the blockchain network and the communication processes involved.

After studying the codebase, I have identified the relevant sections related to node communication. However, I am seeking guidance on the specific steps and considerations necessary to implement this functionality effectively.

Comment: Asking for guidance is off-topic for this website, because the question is not a real programming question. Please try Reddit /r/ethdev or similar tutoring forums.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.